# My if statment and else if statment is not getting executed, but there is not error

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, calculator, calculation

So i'm writing a calculator and I'm struggling with the equal sign, I'm trying to do some simple bedmas (no brachets and no exponents), but my code keeps returning 0 as if the if statment ar egetting totally skipped

I have no idea what is causing this as I'm getting no errors

````
function equal(){
        let exp = document.form.textview.value;
        let expArray = exp.split(/\b/);
        console.log(expArray);   //<-if something doesn't work check this
        let total = 0;
        var lastOperator = "+";
        var lastDig = 0;
        for(let i = 0 ; i < expArray.length; i++){
          var dig = expArray[i].trim(); //value of "i", the item currently in the loop
          if(isNaN(dig) == true){
             console.log("string")
           }
          else if(isNaN(dig) == false){
            console.log('not string');
              if (dig == "/"){ //this whole section gets skipped :(
                var a = i + 1;
                var p = i - 1;
                var aDig = parseFloat(expArray[a].trim); //value after "i"
                var bDig = parseFloat(expArray[p].trim); // value before  "i"
                var sDig = aDig / bDig;
                total = expArray.splice(bDig, 3, sDig);
              }

              else if ( dig == "*"){
                var a = i + 1;
                var p = i - 1;
                var aDig = parseFloat(expArray[a].trim); //value after "i"
                var bDig = parseFloat(expArray[p].trim) // value before  "i"
                var sDig = aDig * bDig;
                total = expArray.splice(bDig, 3, sDig);
              }
              else if ( dig == "+"){
                var a = i + 1;
                var p = i - 1;
                var aDig = parseFloat(expArray[a].trim); //value after "i"
                var bDig = parseFloat(expArray[p].trim)// value before  "i"
                var sDig = aDig + bDig;
                total = expArray.splice(bDig, 3, sDig);
                console.log(expArray.splice(bDig, 3, sDig));
              }
              else if( dig == "-"){
                var a = i + 1;
                var p = i - 1;
                var aDig = parseFloat(expArray[a].trim); //value after "i"
                var bDig = parseFloat(expArray[p].trim) // value before  "i"
                var sDig = aDig - bDig;
                total = expArray.splice(bDig, 3, sDig);
            }
          }

            }
            document.form.textview.value = total;

        } ```
````

Comment: Is `not string` text appear in your console? If yes, please log `dig` variable into console and check what you store in it.

Comment: `isNaN()` checks if the value is not a number, which you are logging correctly. Yet, it feels like you are using it wrong since you make sure that it is a number and then compare it to strings. You should move the sub-ifs to the `console.log("string")` section.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do here.
isNan(numberContent) will return false & isNan(stringContent) will return true.
You are using it wrongly.
The 1st if should be `isNaN(dig) == false` & 2nd  `isNaN(dig) == true`.

````
        let exp = "1/1*3";
        let expArray = exp.split(/\b/);
        console.log(expArray);   //if something doesn't work check this
        var previousValue= parseFloat(expArray[0].trim().toString());
        for(let i = 1 ; i < expArray.length; i++){
        var dig = expArray[i].trim(); //value of "i", the item currently in the loop
          if(isNaN(dig) == false){
             console.log("string")
           }
          else if(isNaN(dig) == true){
            console.log("not string");
            
              var a = i + 1;
              var aDig = previousValue
              var bDig =  parseFloat(expArray[a].trim().toString()); //value after "i"; // value before  "i"
              if (dig == "/"){ //this whole section gets skipped :(
                var sDig = aDig / bDig;
              }

              else if ( dig == "*"){
                var sDig = aDig * bDig;
              }
              else if ( dig == "+"){
                var sDig = aDig + bDig;
                
              }
              else if( dig == "-"){
                var sDig = aDig - bDig;
            }
            previousValue = sDig;
            i++
          }

            }
       alert(previousValue);

        ```
````

Comment: `isNan(string) will return true` note that this is incorrect and I am not meaning the typo.

Comment: Why is it incorrect? I mean isNaN ("string") will return true

Comment: Passing a value of datatype `string` to `isNaN()` will not necessarily return `true`. For example "1", "2      ", "", "     ", "       -1      ".

Comment: Yes. By string I meant, the content is  string.